# How to add a Swift class to module

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

I have an extremely basic Xcode question regarding Swift file's inclusion in modules (I think). I've read many posts on here regarding similar problems, but I believe my misunderstanding is even more basic than what they cover. Although I'm new to Xcode (using version 6.3.2), I've been programming for most of my life on other platforms... so I probably have to unlearn something.

I'm attempting to simply figure out how Xcode adds swift files and the classes in them to the project module. Here's the lcd of what I've done so far:

1) Create a project (iOS > Single View Application), name it (e.g. "Cat"), select language Swift, and save it somewhere.

2) Right click on the Cat folder and select New File. Select iOS > "Swift File", name it "Thing.swift"

3) Create a basic class:

```
import Foundation

public class ThingOne {
    func play(toy: String) -> String {
        let message = "Thing One plays with " + toy
        return message
    }
}
```

4) Try to use the above class in a unit test by importing the module and creating a variable of the above type:

```
import Cat

// [snip]
// Method in the generated test class:
func testExample() {
    let thing1 = Thing()

    // This is an example of a functional test case.
    XCTAssert(true, "Pass")
}
```

...and the "let thing1 = Thing()" gets a "Use of unresolved identifier 'Thing'". Although I've gotten the new class (here called Thing) resolved in some of my test projects due to thrashing, I an unable to get it working on purpose.

What step am I missing? Thank you all for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are trying to do is to have the same source file available both in the application target and in the unit-test target.  You can achieve this by either ticking the right checkbox(es) when you create a new file, or (if you did not do this right away) by ticking corresponding checkbox in File Inspector (Utilities area).

Module in Swift is something different.  You create it by having a `framework` target and building it.  You can use such framework then just like any other framework, and you make its interface available in the application via `import` statement.

This can be of help in understanding the whole thing in detail: [Testing with Xcode](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/DeveloperTools/Conceptual/testing_with_xcode/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014132)